# How to create label_command ind django1.10

Tags: django, django-1.6, django-1.10

I am moving to Django1.10 from django 1.6.11 (I know this is very old. But finally moving to latest version)

My management commands are breaking.

```
class Command(LabelCommand):
    label = 'filename'

    def add_arguments(self, parser):
        parser.add_argument('filename', nargs='+', type=str)

    def handle_label(self, filename, **options):
        print filename
```

Is this the correct way ? The above is not working as expected i.e.

Comment: The method should be named `handle`, not `handle_label`. It will be easier to upgrade to 1.8 LTS first, rather than skipping straight to 1.10. It's even worth testing with 1.7 to make sure you don't miss any depreciation warnings.

Comment: what you meant by `breaking` ?, can you give error you are getting ?

Answer (score 1):

For me the following worked: change

```
parser.add_argument('filename', nargs='+', type=str)
```

to

```
parser.add_argument('args', metavar=self.label, nargs='+')
```

a line which I copied directly `django/django/core/management/base.py` when fixing my LabelCommands when migrating from 1.7 to 1.10.7.

Although what you might want to do is to add substitute the line above with

```
super(Command, self).add_arguments(parser)
```

to maintain forwards compatibility.